# Inability to understand the output of a c program

Tags: c

I have come across a c program in a interview question .The program is as follow:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define x 9+2/4*3-2*4+(5-4)*3
void main()
{

   int i,y,p;
   y=6+3*3/5;
   printf("%d",x);
   i=x*x+y;
   printf("%d",i);

}
```

The output of this program is 30.But I can't understand how the program produce 30.Can anyone explain ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mre], and [edit] your question to copy-paste it into the question itself (as text).

Comment: As a possible hint: Think about what the result of an ***integer*** division is. What do your text-books say?

Comment: Because you are doing division with ``int`` types.

Comment: `#define`, in this specific case, does simple text replacement.

Answer (score 1):

`#define`, in your specific case, does simple text replacement.

First expression (for `x`) is

```
9+2/4*3-2*4+(5-4)*3
9+ 0 *3-2*4+  1  *3
9+  0  - 8 +    3
  9    - 8 +    3
     1     +    3
          4
```

Second expression (for `i`) is

```
9+2/4*3-2*4+(5-4)*3*9+2/4*3-2*4+(5-4)*3+y // y is 7
9+2/4*3-2*4+(5-4)*3*9+2/4*3-2*4+(5-4)*3+7 // doing parenthesis
9+2/4*3-2*4+  1  *3*9+2/4*3-2*4+  1  *3+7 // doing multiplications and divisions
9+ 0 *3- 8 +    3  *9+ 0 *3- 8 +    3  +7 // doing multiplications and divisions again
9+   0 - 8 +    27   +  0  - 8 +    3  +7 // doing addition and subtraction left to right
   9   - 8 +    27   +  0  - 8 +    3  +7
       1   +    27   +  0  - 8 +    3  +7
            28       +  0  - 8 +    3  +7
                28         - 8 +    3  +7
                      20       +    3  +7
                               23      +7
                                   30
```

When writing `#defines` with operations **always** enclose the whole thing inside an extra set parenthesis:

```
#define x (9+2/4*3-2*4+(5-4)*3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Integer division is part of the answer, but the trickier part is the `#define`. Many people assume that a `#define` is evaluated when it is defined, but it is really just a simple text substitution. So when you are given `x*x`, you get

```
9+2/4*3-2*4+(5-4)*3*9+2/4*3-2*4+(5-4)*3
```

Note that is the middle of this you have `3*9`, which you would not get if you assumed `x` was a simple numeric value. Heres the whole process:

```
  x * x
= 9+2/4*3-2*4+(5-4)*3*9+2/4*3-2*4+(5-4)
= 9 +  0 - 8 +    27   +  0  - 8 +  3
=        1   +    27   -     5
=              23
```

Then, since `y=7`, `23 + 7 = 30`

Voila

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reasonable and understandable reply